# Error:Missing argument for parameter 'makePetMakeNoise' in call

Tags: swift

Hi I am doing some Swift coding and I cant figure out how to get rid of this error:

> Missing argument for parameter 'makePetMakeNoise' in call.

Could you help me fix this error?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Human {
    static var numCreated:Int = 4
    var name:String = ""
    var pet:Pet

    init(name:String,pet:Pet){
        self.name = name
        self.pet = pet
        Human.numCreated++
    }
    func makePetMakeNoise(){ 
        var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(9)
        self.pet.makeNoise(randomNumber) //Missing argument for parameter        'makePetMakeNoise' in call
    }

    func feedPet(){
        self.pet.eat
    }

    static func populationCount(){  
        println("Total population count is \(Human.numCreated)")
    } 
    }
    class Pet {
        var name:String = ""
        var noise:String = ""
        var canMakeNoise:Bool = true

    init(name:String,noise:String,canMakeNoise:Bool){
        self.name = name
        self.noise = noise
        self.canMakeNoise = canMakeNoise

    }

    func makeNoise(canMakeNoise: Int, makePetMakeNoise: Int){


        if self.canMakeNoise { 

            for _ in 1...5{
                println("\(self.name) \(self.noise)")

            }

        }else {
            println("\(self.name) *remains silent*")

        }

    }

    func eat(){
        println("\(name) is eating")
    }


    class Dog:Pet{
    }

    class Cat:Pet{
        override func eat {
            super.eat()
            println("I'm still hungry, meow")
        }
    }
    }

    //Pets
    var Tobie = Pet(name: "Tobie", noise: "Bark", canMakeNoise: true)
    var Bud = Pet(name: "Bud", noise: "Bark", canMakeNoise: false)
    var Ginger = Pet(name: "Ginger", noise: "bark", canMakeNoise: false)
    var Curry = Pet(name: "Curry", noise: "Bark", canMakeNoise: true)
    //Humans
    var Sam = Human(name: "Sam", pet: Tobie)
    var Mark = Human(name: "Mark", pet: Bud)
    var Spencer = Human(name: "Spencer", pet: Ginger)
    var Jessie = Human(name: "Jessie", pet: Curry)
    let Humans = [Sam, Mark, Spencer, Jessie]


    for Human in Humans {
        println("\(Humans) \(feedPet) \(makePetMakeNoise)") //Use of unresolved identifier 'feedPet and makePetMakeNoise'\\ 
    }




`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `makeNoise` method defined for `Pet` takes two parameters. Problem is that when you call it in the line that gives you the error, you pass it just one parameter.

Possible solution is:
Change the `Pet`'s method as follow:

```
func makeNoise(makePetMakeNoise: Int){


        if self.canMakeNoise {

            for _ in 1...5{
                println("\(self.name) \(self.noise)")

            }

        }else {
            println("\(self.name) *remains silent*")

        }

    }
```

Update the code that gives you the error in `Human` like this:

```
func makePetMakeNoise(){
        var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(9))
        self.pet.makeNoise(randomNumber)
}
```

Notice I convert `random` to `Int` since this is the expected parameter type.

Please consider I'm just guessing a possible modification since I don't know what your classes are intended for ... maybe just a playground.

Other solution is effectively passing two parameters when you call the pet's method from human.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Your function `func makeNoise(canMakeNoise: Int, makePetMakeNoise: Int)` expects two arguments, but your are only passing the one `randonNumber` in your call `self.pet.makeNoise(randomNumber)`. It should look something like this: `self.pet.makeNoise(randomNumber, someOtherNumber)`